# Cannot access network share - "The user has not been granted the requested logon type"

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, network-shares

The issue is that I have a username and password setup on the computer I'm trying to access, but I'm not being prompted to enter the credentials for the network share I'm trying to access. It just flat out says denied.

The server is running Windows 7 Pro, and the client trying to access the server is Windows 8 Pro. The same happens as well when I try to connect to it from a Windows 7 Pro computer...

Answer (score 3):

Start > Programs > Administrative Tools > Local Security Policy

Security Settings > Local Policies > User Rights Assignment

Doube click **Access this computer from the network** and check that the user(s) in question are in the list.

Comment: But as I said, it's not even asking me to supply a username. It's supposedly trying to use the username that I'm currently logged into on the remote system, but that user doesn't exist (nor do I want it to) on the server. I had setup a special account "Network$" to be used for network access to specific shares. I want to use that user, but it's not prompting me to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the underlying NTFS permissions on the files behind your network$ share that are causing the Access Denied message?  
  What happens if you share out another folder, perhaps one without a dollar sign, just in case that's the problem?

Comment: It's not the share - I can't even access the root of the windows shares. Also, Network$ is the username not the share name. I shared out My Videos and made sure that NTFS permissions on the share and the folder allow full access to that user, but again - it's not asking me to input a username to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Microsoft problem. I am a system administrator and I encounter this problem every day.

In some cases, you can't either connect the systems via homegroup. The quick solution is to disable password protection sharing, via advanced sharing options in *Networks and Sharing* section on the server.

After doing that, go to the `gpedit.msc`, and remove "everyone" from the list, while you also add the domain name/computer/user(s) which you want to gain "static" (in IT language) network access to the server.

But when you want a new computer to access the server, you have to add it to this list.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check is the '**Deny access to this computer from the network**' policy, which overrides the 'allow access' policy if the same user is in both.